# strlwr() function in C not working despite library included and linked?

Tags: c, string, function, libraries

I'm on Linux Gallium OS 4.16.18 using VSCode following a beginner's tutorial in C.

The code example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char string1[] = "Bro";
    char string2[] = "Code"; 

    strlwr(string1, string2);


    printf("%s", string1);

    return 0;
}
```

Warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlwr’; did you mean ‘strlen’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 strlwr(string1, string2);
 ^~~~~~
```

Refuses to compile:

```
undefined reference to 'strlwr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The fact that string2 is not being used shouldn't concern us, it's there for the next step in his tutorial. This program should compile anyway but for me it doesn't.

What's interesting is that an earlier tutorial using the <math.h> library didn't work for me either. I looked up the error and found out that my VSCode doesn't link the libraries like I want it to. I wasn't smart enough to configure it correctly, but I was able to circumvent the problem:
For just this one example using the <math.h> library I compiled the code outside VSCode using

```
GCC myprogram.c -o myprogram -lm
```

In this case -lm was needed to link the math library and the program compiled!

Now I've tried the same thing with this <string.h> library but to no avail.

https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/s/strlwr.html

This site says 'strlwr' belongs to the library 'libc':

> Use the -l c option to qcc to link against this library. This library
> is usually included automatically.

But like I mentioned, adding -lc to my GCC compiling command didn't work. What's even weirder is that Wikipedia says 'strlwr' isn't even part of the <string.h> library.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling

and this site seems to agree (in German though).

[https://www2.hs-fulda.de/~klingebiel/c-stdlib/string.htm](https://www2.hs-fulda.de/%7Eklingebiel/c-stdlib/string.htm)

But in every tutorial I find online it works like a charm using only <string.h>.

If I use `strcat` which IS found in <string.h> my program compiles even in VSCode without error or warning.

What's going on here?

Comment: `strlwr` is part Microsoft's C library. What OS are you using?

Comment: Oh lord... yeah, I'm on Linux. I didn't know that was a thing. Thank you.

Comment: Totally missed the first line xD

Comment: Should be pretty easy to implement though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user **alex01011** pointed out 'strlwr' is a Microsoft library and I was using Linux.

Solved.